# Why can this equation be written as determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, circles

$$A(x^2+y^2)+Bx+Cy+D=0$$

is the equation of a circle in the plane provided $A\ne0$.
The equation above can be written as the determinant
$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        x^2+y^2 & x & y & 1 \\
        x_1^2+y_1^2 & x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
        x_2^2+y_2^2 & x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
        x_3^2+y_3^2 & x_3 & y_3 & 1 \\
        \end{vmatrix}
        = 0,
$$
where
$$
        A =
        \begin{vmatrix}
        x_1 & y_1 & 1 \\
        x_2 & y_2 & 1 \\
        x_3 & y_3 & 1 \\
        \end{vmatrix},
        B =
        \begin{vmatrix}
        x_1^2+y_1^2 & y_1 & 1 \\
        x_2^2+y_2^2 & y_2 & 1 \\
        x_3^2+y_3^2 & y_3 & 1 \\
        \end{vmatrix},
$$
$$
        C =
        \begin{vmatrix}
        x_1^2+y_1^2 & x_1 & 1 \\
        x_2^2+y_2^2 & x_2 & 1 \\
        x_3^2+y_3^2 & x_3 & 1 \\
        \end{vmatrix},
        D =
        \begin{vmatrix}
        x_1^2+y_1^2 & x_1 & y_1 \\
        x_2^2+y_2^2 & x_2 & y_2 \\
        x_3^2+y_3^2 & x_3 & y_3 \\
        \end{vmatrix}.
$$
$P_1(x_1, y_1, z_1)$, $P_2(x_2, y_2, z_2)$, $P_3(x_3, y_3, z_3)$ are 3 points defining the circle and $P(x, y, z)$ is an arbitrary point.

Comment: What is the probability distribution of the "random point" $P(x,y,z)$?

Comment: @uniquesolution Sorry. I mean arbitrary.

Comment: Remember the alternating signs in the Laplace expansion of the determinant? $B$ and $D$ need changed signs accordingly.

Comment: @ccorn This is taken from a book. $B$ and $D$ don't have minus signs.

Comment: Too bad for the book.

Comment: This is just Laplace expansion of determinant along the first row, but signs are suspicious.

Comment: Maybe it is an error in the book. If $B$ and $D$ have minus signs, I think I can understand now.

Comment: Four equations written for points $P(x,y,z)$ and $P_1,P_2,P_3$ in the matrix $A$ form.   The system of equations has non-zero solution only if $ \det(A)=0$